# Why did the .NET framework developers chose 10 (on x64 12) as factor while unrolling the loop?

Tags: c#, string, equals, simd

Look in the C# Original Code, I see the method of string's [EqualsHelper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,11648d2d83718c5e):

```
    // unroll the loop 
#if AMD64 
    // for AMD64 bit platform we unroll by 12 and
    // check 3 qword at a time. This is less code 
    // than the 32 bit case and is shorter pathlength

    while (length >= 12) 
    {
        if (*(long*)a     != *(long*)b) break; 
        if (*(long*)(a+4) != *(long*)(b+4)) break; 
        if (*(long*)(a+8) != *(long*)(b+8)) break;
        a += 12; b += 12; length -= 12; 
    }
#else
    while (length >= 10)
    { 
        if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) break;
        if (*(int*)(a+2) != *(int*)(b+2)) break; 
        if (*(int*)(a+4) != *(int*)(b+4)) break; 
        if (*(int*)(a+6) != *(int*)(b+6)) break;
        if (*(int*)(a+8) != *(int*)(b+8)) break; 
        a += 10; b += 10; length -= 10;
    }
#endif
```

I want to know why the loop unrolls by 10 or 12, if this because of the CPU's optimization: the SIMD(Single Instruction Multiple Data)?

Why don't I write in this way directly:

```
while (length > 0) 
{
    if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) break;
    a += 2; b += 2; length -= 2;
}
```

Comment: What does the comment say (re: 12)?

Comment: @mjwills, It says it unrolls by factor 12 because its path is shorter and less code than the 32-bit variant. So, why did they choose factor 10 for the 32-bit variant?

Comment: I think the more interesting question to ask is why this unrolling is done in .NET source rather than by the JIT/AOD (which should always be able to tune to the specific target processor).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can't the JIT still optimize the unrolled code whenever it passes the JIT.compile method?